# How do I share or setup a tunnel with two Internet connections?

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, ssh, home-networking

My current network topology is:

[image: Network Topology]

As you can see, my PC has no Internet connection, but my laptop does.

As it is (in the picture), the laptop accesses the Internet with no problems, and both laptop and PC can ping each other. I have installed VNC Tight (remote desktop) on the laptop, and it works no problem.

So the question, what are my viable options to share internet access to my PC? I was thinking:

- Somehow setup an SSH tunnel, (PC connects to Laptop, then Laptop redirects to the wireless connection)

I've tried to enable Internet connection share (ICS), but in Windows 7 Starter Edition it is not available.

I'm not an expert in networks, so I don't even know if I even have options to solve this particular problem.

Additional details:

- Laptop has Windows 7 Starter Edition
- PC has Windows 7 Ultimate Edition

Comment: Run any proxy software you like on the laptop. You can use FreeProxy, WinGate, CCProxy, or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your laptop would need to "share" it's internet connection. Usually that means setting up a "proxy" server (which is more or less a fancy way of saying share a connection). It's no big deal but those concepts may be what you're looking to do. Here are a few links to help you get started:

http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/675-how-to-configure-proxy-settings-in-windows-7/

http://www.techradar.com/news/networking/how-to-set-up-a-proxy-server-704981

Then again, this may be way outside your level of expertise but just in case it isn't you may want to consider dual booting your laptop with something like Proxmox. For more on that here's a link:

http://www.proxmox.com/

Hope it helps. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying WinGate but for some reason I couldn't connect to  my laptop (even tho I can ping/http/VNC tight). I'm going to try with your techradar link.

Comment: It worked with FreeProxy, finally!